# Como exportar tablas generadas con EXPSS en R a EXCEL en diferentes "sheets"

Tags: r, excel, tablas

Tengo un par de tablas que he generado mediante la función `fre()` en R. Son tablas de frecuencias simples. Deseo exportar cada tabla a excel, pero en diferentes "sheets".
He estado usando los siguientes códigos de openxlsx y expss para guardar una tabla en una pestaña:

```
wb = createWorkbook()  
sh = addWorksheet(wb, "tabla_1")  
xl_write(table_1, wb, sh)  
saveWorkbook(wb, "tables.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Sin embargo, cuando intento guardar en diferentes pestañas se me complica. A veces el archivo xlsx tiene varias pestañas pero solo una tiene tabla. Otras veces se guarda la misma tabla en en las diferentes pestañas. Si alguien conoce una forma me podría indicar por favor.

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola!

A mi me resulta de utilidad la función `write.xlsx` de la librería `xlsx``.

Suponiendo que queremos guardar las tablas `table_1`, `table_2` y `table_3`, cada una en una hoja diferente del mismo Excel, basta con ejecutar el siguiente código:

```
write.xlsx(table_1, "NombreExcel.xlsx", sheetName = "NombreHoja1")
wirte.xlsx(table_2, "NombreExcel.xlsx", sheetName = "NombreHoja2", append = TURE)
wirte.xlsx(table_3, "NombreExcel.xlsx", sheetName = "NombreHoja3", append = TURE)
```

La clave está en que la primera vez se crea el documento y en las posteriores, la opción `append = TRUE` es la que determina que se cree una nueva hoja (o *sheet*) en la que guardar la información.

Comment: Hola @R18,  sí conozco esa función. El único problema es que solo me rellena el excel con los datos. Lo que necesito es que se guarde con el formato y la distribución de la tabla crear con la función  `fre()`. Por eso he empleado el `xl_write` porque funciona bien con el expss.

Comment: De acuerdo, ahora entiendo. No conozco muy bien la función, pero veo que hay unos parámetros que son `sheet` y `sheetname`, ¿qué ocurre si le llamas con un nombre distinto a cada tabla que quieras guardar?

Comment: Pasa que o se borran los datos de un sheet o se copia la misma base de datos en ambos sheets. Sin embargo, ya lo resolví pues era un tema secuencia que debía seguir. Aunque me gustaría evitar esa secuencia y ver una manera de emplear una función.